# how to show a full page image on website on load which hide after user click?

Tags: javascript, php

I am newbie programmer and I don't know how I can show .jpg image after my website load. I want to set it on whole page (100% height and width) and allow it to hide after user click.

Comment: What did you try to achieve this first?  Please at least search around the web for what you're after, and only post specific questions to specific problems.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly as it will vastly improve your chances of getting good answers in return and not have your question downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 0):

Via HTML

```
<img style="width:100%;height:100%" id="image" src="...">
```

or CSS

```
#image
{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Then in your javascript

```
// add event listener to the image    
var el = document.getElementById("image");
el.addEventListener("click", hide_img, false);
function hide_img(){
   this.style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>//this is javascript...
window.onload=()=>{
 //when the page loaded create new image
 img=document.createElement("img");
 //set the image data
 img.src="img.jpg";
 img.style.height="100%";
 img.style.width="100%";
 //onclick remove image
 img.onclick=()=>{
 img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
 };
 //add image to page
 document.body.appendChild(img);
 }
 </script>
```